# Rails builds invalid sql query for has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a models like below

```
# Base model
class RecordBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'records'

  has_many :record_images, as: assetable, dependent: :destroy

  fileuploads :record_images
end

# Inherited model
class SpecificRecord < RecordBase
end

# Image model
class RecordImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Uploader::Asset

  belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I'm using https://github.com/superp/rails-uploader for upload files. I have record of `RecordImage` model in database with `assetable_id` corresponding to `SpecificRecord` record and `assetable_type` `'SpecificRecord'` but when I try `SpecificRecord.find(some_id).record_images` in console, rails builds sql query with `assetable_type` `'RecordBase'` and hence finds nothing. How to specify which `assetable_type` should be in sql query?

#### Update

That's issue about `rails-uploader` gem, in version '0.2.8' gem redefined [`.base_class`](https://github.com/superp/rails-uploader/blob/v0.2.8/lib/uploader/fileuploads.rb#L78) and saves data to db with `assetable_type` of child class, but in version '0.4.5' assets saves to db with `assetable_type` of base class.

Comment: Since it is an STI, I don't see it as a problem because the `id` will be unique across resulting `RecordBase.find(1)` to be equal to `SpecificRecord.find(1)`.

Comment: @Md. Farhan Memon `RecordBase` records search working fine, but when I try to get all associated to the `SpecificRecord` records rails tries to find them by `assetable_id` and `assetable_type` where `assetable_id` is correct, but `assetable_type` in sql query is `RecordBase` but `RecordImage` records has `assetable_type` `SpecificRecord`